# How to get the position of an orbiting sphere

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to get the position of a sphere that is rotating around an idle object in my opengl application. This is how I perform the orbiting:

```
            glTranslatef(positions[i].getPosX(), //center of rotation (yellow ball)
                           positions[i].getPosY(),
                           positions[i].getPosZ());
            glRotatef(rotation_angle,0.0,1.0,0.0); //angle of rotation
            glTranslatef(distance[i].getPosX(), //distance from the center of rotation
                           distance[i].getPosY(),
                           distance[i].getPosZ());
```

Variable *rotation_angle* loops from 0 to 360 endlessly. In the distance vector I'm only changing the z-distance of the object, for example let's say the idle object is in (0,0,0), the distance vector could be (0,0,200).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL just draws stuff. It doesn't maintain a "scene". So you'll have to do all the math yourself. This is as simple as multiplying the vector (0,0,0,1) with the current modelview-projection matrix and perform viewport remapping. This has been conveniently packed up in the GLU (not OpenGL) function [`gluProject`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluProject.xml).

Since you're using the (old-and-busted) fixed function pipeline the procedure follows about

```
GLdouble x,y,z;
GLdouble win_x, win_y, win_z;
GLdouble mv[16], prj[16];
GLint vp[4];
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mv);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, prj);
glGetInteger(GL_VIEWPORT, vp);
gluProjection(x,y,z, mv, prj, vp, win_x, win_y, win_z);
```

Note that due to OpenGL's stateful nature the value of the modelview and projection matrix and the viewport *at the moment of drawing the sphere* matters. Retrieving those values at any other moment may produce very different data and result in an outcome inconsistent with the drawing.

Comment: Mh, this seemed to work but instead I get strange results. I was expecting to see in win_x, win_y, win_z the actual position of the sphere that is orbiting, but it isn't so. The idle object that is in the middle of the orbit is centered in X=0, y=0, but win_x and win_y are never (0,0).

Comment: @Andrew: Position of the sphere with respect to *what*? The solution I gave you gives you the position in window coordinates… which is all OpenGL does care about. As already told, OpenGL does not maintain a scene, so between the window position and the local coordinates of the vertices the only spaces you could tap into are the view space (after modelview transform) and clip space (after projection transform). These transformations boil down to simple vector matrix multiplication (multiply vertex position with modelview matrix to get into view space).